# c++ classes and pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, pointers

I have got this HW question

> Create an enumerator called gender with two possible values, male and female.

The Person class definition is given in the following code. Implement it all with all required class(es) and enumerator(s) and test all member functions in the main.

```
#ifndef Person_h
#define Person_h
#include <iostream>
#include "address.h" // header file for the Address class
#include "gender.h" // header file for the Gender enum 
using namespace std;
class Person
{
  public:
    Person();
    Person(const char * n, const Gender * g, const Address * ad);
    Person(const Person & f);
    void setName(char * n);
    void setAds( Address * ad ); 
    char * getName()const ;
    Address *getAds()const ;
    ~Person();
private:
    char * name;
    Gender * gender; 
      Address * ads;
      };
#endif
```

here is my attempt:

address.h

```
#pragma once
class Address
{
public:
    Address(const char *streetv="noName", const char*telv="noTel", const int POBoxv=0);
    Address(Address &address);
    ~Address();
    void setAll(const char *streetv, const char*telv, const int POBoxv);
char *getStreet()const;
char *getTe ()const;
int getPOBox()const;
void setStreet(char *str);
void setTel(char *t);
void setPOBox(int po);

private:
    char *street;
    char *tel;
    int POBox;

};

enum Gender{Male,Female,unknown};
```

address.cpp

```
#include "Address.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


Address::Address(const char *streetv, const char*telv, const int POBoxv)

{
    street=new char[30];
    strcpy(street,streetv);
    tel=new char[30];
    strcpy(tel,telv);
    POBox=POBoxv;

}
```

Person.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Address.h"
class Person
{
public:
    Person();
    Person(const char * n, const Gender * g, const Address * ad);
    Person(const Person & f);
    void setName(char * n);
    void setAds( Address * ad ); 
    char * getName()const ;
    Address *getAds()const ;
    ~Person();
private:
    char * name;
    Gender * gender; 
      Address * ads;

};
```

Person.cpp

```
#include "Person.h"
#include "Address.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

Person::Person()
{
    name=new char[30];
    strcpy(name,"unknown");
    gender=new Gender;
    *gender=unknown;
    ads->setAll("unknown","unknown",0);
}

Person::Person(const char * n, const Gender * g, const Address * ad)

{
    name=new char[30];
    strcpy(name,n);
    *gender=Male;
     *ads=*ad;

}



void Person:: setName(char * n){

    name=new char[30];
    strcpy(name,n);
}


void Person:: setAds( Address * ad ){

    ads=ad;
}

char* Person::getName()const{

    return name;
}

Address* Person::getAds()const{

    return ads;
}



Person::Person(const Person & f){
    name=f.name;
    gender=f.gender;
    ads=f.ads;

}

Person::~Person(void)
{
    delete [] name;
}
```

main

```
#include "Address.h"
#include "Person.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


void main(){
    Address ad("New street","0501234567",1234);
    //testing Person();
    Person pe;
    cout<<"Name: "<<pe.getName()<<" Street: "<<pe.getAds()<<endl;

    //testing Person(const char * n, const Gender * g, const Address * ad);
    Person p ("Adam",Male,ad);
    cout<<"Name: "<<pe.getName()<<" Street: "<<pe.getAds()<<endl;

    //testing Person(const Person & f);
    Person p2 (pe);
    cout<<p2.getAds()<<endl;

    //testing set functions
    p2.setName("Ali");
    p2.setAds(&ad);

    //testing get functions

    cout<<"Name: "<<pe.getName()<<" Street: "<<pe.getAds()<<endl;
}
```

The compiler keep highlighting the word "Adam" in main at this line

```
Person p ("Adam",Male,ad);
```

because "no constructors "Person::Person" match the argument list"

also even when I delete that line, the compiler keep crashing without giving a reason
can you please help?

Comment: Where is `Adam` declared?

Comment: Strings need to have quotes on them.  `Adam` => `"Adam"`

Comment: Moreover, that's some old school-looking code, including the supplied header. Too bad you're not being taught modern C++: You're going to have to re-learn *a lot* in the future.

Comment: @NathanOliver I did write "Adam" with quotes in my code but I don't know how it got removed when I wrote it here. It still the same problem when I write adam with quotes "no constructors "Person::Person" match the argument list"

Comment: @Adam If the compiler does indeed *crash*, as you say, then that's a bug in the compiler and not something we can solve here. If, instead, it is in fact a matter of the compiler *giving you an error*, then you should post that *exact* error here. After having perused it yourself, of course.

Comment: @Adam As for the error regarding no matching constructors; it's just that. `Person` doesn't have a constructor that takes three arguments of those types. Note that `Gender` and `Gender*` are *not* the same things, same goes for `Address` and `Address*`.

Comment: @Adam `Person p ("Adam",Male,ad);` => `Person p ("Adam","Male",ad);`  If this how it is in your actual code then let me know.  SO should not have removed any quotes from your code.

Comment: @Adam Intellisense is dumb. Recompile, reindex. If there are real compiler errors state them verbatim in your question please.

Comment: The `Person` constructor that is closest takes 3 pointers. You haven't supplied pointers.

Comment: @Biffen how this is an old school code? can you please tell me more to fix this problem at early stages ?

Comment: @Adam Pointers everywhere. C-style strings. Virtually *no* RAII (that might just be your implementation, but I suspect you're just doing what you've been taught).

Comment: @BoPersson you are right can you please be more specific on how to fix this?

Comment: @Adam Use `std::string` for strings, not `char *` or char arrays.

Comment: What is the point of making the members private if you provide public accessors and mutators for all of them?

Comment: @Adam - The given interface is strange, but as it requires the parameters to be pointers, you have to store those in some variables and then pass their addresses. This also forces you to copy all values in the constructors, just like you do with the names. Otherwise you will get all kinds of new problems.

Comment: @Adam That's far from a [MCVE] to reproduce the error, just remove all of the irrelevant stuff, but show what `Gender` actually is please!

Comment: `Gender` is in `address.h`, strangely enough.

Comment: @Biffen Ah, I didn't even spot it, as this is the least place where I'd expect the definition, especially when spotting `#include "gender.h" ` from OPs task requirements.

Comment: @Adam Why in the world is `gender` a pointer?  `gender=new Gender;
    *gender=unknown;`??  Just make it a non-pointer member and assign it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Probably because their teacher wanted it to be a pointer. I think the teacher already has a problem, giving good interfaces for exercises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposed `Gender` is a enum type (as it should be), the problem is, the constructor signature expects a pointer for the `Gender` enum parameter:

```
 Person::Person(const char * n, const Gender * g, const Address * ad)
                             // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but you pass the plain enum value in `main()`:

```
Person p ("Adam",Male,ad);
              // ^^^^
```

The constructor signature should be changed to

```
 Person::Person(const char * n, Gender g, const Address * ad)
                             // ^^^^^^^^
```

or you should take a (optionally `const`) enum variable's address when calling:

```
const Gender g = Male;
Person p ("Adam",&g,ad);
              // ^
```

---

Also note, whatever was given for the `Gender` constructor parameter, isn't used in your definition:

```
Person::Person(const char * n, const Gender * g, const Address * ad) {
    name=new char[30];
    strcpy(name,n);
    *gender=Male; // <<<<< Always initialized to Male, regardless g's value, and no memory allocated at all
    *ads=*ad;
}
```

should be:

```
 gender = new Gender(*g);
```

Comment: Note that the value of `g` is not used by the `Person` constructor. All instances of `Person` must have the gender `Male`.

Comment: @BoPersson Fixed. _"Terrible interface! "_ Absolutely agreed!

Comment: @Derek That's a sexist class definition, shame on the OP ;-).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  ahh I see thank you but it keeps highlighting "Adam" because "no constructors "Person::Person" match the argument list"

Comment: @Adam Well, as mentioned intellisense is dumb.

Comment: @Adam There's a lot more flaws with the code you show. I'm giving up as explaining far these points. If that was seriously the assignment given for your homework, you should consider quitting that course, or attend your principal and tell them that teacher should be considered for retirement.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ First thank you so much now I begin to see my mistakes. and  yah lol it's an assignment and I have to solve it as it says in question. why I should I do that? can you give me more details on what is wrong with the assignment ?

Comment: @Adam Well, neither `Gender` nor `Address` parameters should be pointers, also the `const char*` parameter should be a `const std::string &` rather. That's simply not the way, we're declaring real world c++ interfaces. Your teacher requires you to do useless stuff, that overcomplicates the whole thing and leave you more confused instead of learning how things actually work in c++.